# C - how to read a txt file how many string split by space?

Tags: c, string, file, text

I have text file which include thousands of string

but each string split by a space " "

How can i count how many strings there are?

Comment: By reading from the file using the `myfile` pointer. And then searching for white spaces and counting them.

Comment: can u provide code?

Comment: NO, I can't. You should try something, if there is no effort you don't deserve the help! `fopen(path, "r")` is no effort at all.

Comment: right! ^......^

Comment: I had tried, but it need initial the char before, how not to initial the char line? plz see my edit

Comment: @iharob  .........

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `strtok()` as you only need to count the number of space characters.

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, myfile) != NULL) {
    for (size_t i = 0; line[i]; i++) {
        if (line[i] == ' ') totalStrings++;
    }
}
```

If you want to consider *any* whitespace character then you can use [`isspace()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) function.

You can read character by character as well without using an array:

```
int ch;
while ((ch=fgetc(myfile)) != EOF) {
    if (ch == ' ') totalStrings++;
}
```

But I don't see why you want to avoid using an array as it would probably be more efficient (reading more chars at a time rather than reading one byte at a time).

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` function will read entire line from file (you need to know maximum possible size of that line. Then, you can use `strtok()` from ` to parse the string and count the words.

Comment: You are wrong on [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). It will *not* read an entire line from a file (not always), and you do *not* need to know the length of the longest line. Please read its description, and see the example in that same link.

Comment: "The C library function char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream) reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to by str. It stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first." - if you know how long you _line_ is going to be, `fgets()` can do what I wrote it would do.

Comment: My point is, you do not *need* to know the length of the lines to use `fgets`. Either the returned string ends with a newline, and then you know you've read "a line", or it does not, and then you're at the end of the file or the buffer is full. (For OP's purpose, he doesn't even need to read entire lines, so a buffer size of 2 would already be enough. Note that he says "thousands of string in a one line".)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`fgetc()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm), you can count the spaces.

Take note that in cases wherein there are spaces at the beginning of the string, those will be counted as well and it is okay if spaces are present on the start of the line. Else, it won't give accurate results as the first string won't be counted because it has no space before it.

To solve that, we need to check first the first character and increment the string counter if it is an alphabet character.

```
int str_count = 0;
int c;

// first char
if( isalpha(c = fgetc(myfile)) )
    str_count++;
else
    ungetc(c, myfile);
```

Then, we loop through the rest of the contents.
Checking if an alphabet character follows a space will verify if there is a next string after the space, else a space at the end of the line will be counted as well, giving an inaccurate result.

```
do
{
    c = fgetc(myfile);
    if( c == EOF )
         break;

    if(isspace(c)) {
        if( isalpha(c = fgetc(myfile)) ) {
            str_count++;
            ungetc(c, myfile);

        } else if(c == '\n') { // for multiple newlines
            str_count++;
        }
    }

} while(1);
```

Tested on a [Lorem Ipsum generator](http://www.lipsum.com/) of 1500 words:
http://pastebin.com/w6EiSHbx